# AudioKit: createVirtualPorts do not forward portIDs

Tags: swift, audiokit

When I create virtual MIDI ports, the PortID that I define do not work, instead, default PortIDs (2000000 and 2000001) are used to create the input and output ports.

The bug seems to be in MIDI+VirtualPorts.swift line 26 and line 27.
The uniqueIDs are not forwarded from line 23.

I do realise that each port (input and output) need to have unique IDs, so a fix could be something like adding 1 to each of the created outputports.

Comment: Seems like something better suited for the AudioKit issues page on Github, as I don't think the StackOverflow community will be of much help.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll see if I can create an issue on GitHub.